Bound on norm of least squares solution
Suppose we have a linear system $Ax = b$ where $A$ is $n \times m$ for $n > m$ and has full column rank. The least squares solution is given by $x = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$. What upper bound can be given for $||x||$ in terms of $||b||$?
One direct route is to bound $||x||$ via the operator norms of both $(A^T A)^{-1}$ and $A^T$. However, I hope that there should be a bound in terms of only the smallest singular value of $A^T A$. This previous question gives such a bound but is (implicitly) specific to the case of an underdetermined system, as opposed to the overdetermined one described here. In particular, the form of the pseudo-inverse/solution is different.

The nonzero singular values of $A^TA$ are the same as the nonzero singular values of $AA^T$ and both are equal to the squares of the singular values of $A$ and $A^T$

Thanks. Being more precise, I am searching for a bound that depends only on the operator norm of $(A^T A)^{-1}$, i.e., the smallest singular values, not the largest (as would figure into the operator norm of $A^T$)

Use the SVD to show that $|(A^T A)^{-1} A^T | =\sigma_{min}(A)^{-1} $

Based on the strategy suggested in the comments: using the SVD $A = U \Sigma V^T$, we have that $(A^TA)^{-1}A = V \Sigma^+ U^T$ where $\Sigma^+$ is the pseudo-inverse of $\Sigma$. Accordingly, $||A^TA)^{-1}A|| = \sigma_{min}(A)^{-1} = \sigma_{min}(A^T A)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ (where the last step can be shown by expressing $A^TA$ in terms of the SVD of A). Therefore, we have that $||x|| \leq \sigma_{min}(A^T A)^{-\frac{1}{2}} ||b||$.
